# Converting ANTLR AST to Java bytecode using ASM

Tags: compiler, jvm

I am currently trying to write my own compiler, targeting the JVM.

I have completed the parsing step using Java classes generated by [ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/antlr/info), and have an AST of the source code to work from (An ANTLR "CommonTree", specifically). I am using ASM to simplify the generating of the bytecode.

**Could anyone give a broad overview of how to convert this AST to bytecode?**

My current strategy is to explore down the tree, generating different code depending on the current node (using "Tree.getType()").

The problem is that I can only recognise tokens from my lexer this way, rather than more complex patterns from the parser.

**Is there something I am missing, or am I simply approaching this wrong?**

Comment: To emit java bytecode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016305/how-to-emit-and-execute-java-bytecode-at-runtime

Answer (score 3):

This is simply too large a topic to cover in a Q/A forum.  You need to buy / borrow and read a textbook on compiler writing that has good coverage of code generation.

> The problem is that I can only recognise tokens from my lexer this way, rather than more complex patterns from the parser.

I don't understand this.  Do you mean that you don't have a symbol table?  If not, you'll need one.  A good textbook will explain this concept and how to implement it.

---

If someone would care to suggest an up-to-date textbook, feel free.  (I have a copy of the Dragon Book ... but it is pretty dated.)

Comment: Hmmm. I have done some further reading, and it seems one can use a "Tree Grammar" to generate bytecode. I presume this makes things more "automatic"?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing something along the same lines. I recommend Pragmatic's ANTLR The Definitive Guide and also Pragmatic's Language Implementation Patterns both available at their website  (with which I have zero connection)  .. I would say that both these books taken together are better than the Dragon